# create a new record type for an object inside testing environment using apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, record-type

I have a function that fetches record types for a list of sObjects. It adds each record type, along with the sObject name, to a resultMap if it exists. I need to create a mock record type for testing purposes within the test environment. This mock record type should be rolled back once testing is complete. This approach is necessary because the record types for sObjects can vary across different environments, making it difficult to predict consistent results. Here's my code and test, any help would be appreciated.

Function:

```
    public static Map<String, List<String>> fetchObjectRecordTypes(
    List<String> sObjectList
  ) {
    Map<String, List<String>> objectRecordTypesMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
    try{
      for (String salesforceObj : sObjectList) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjectDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
          ?.get(salesforceObj)
          ?.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeInfos = sObjectDescribe.getRecordTypeInfos();
        List<String> recordTypeNames = new List<String>();
        for (Schema.RecordTypeInfo recordTypeInfo : recordTypeInfos) {
          if (recordTypeInfo.getDeveloperName() != 'Master') {
            recordTypeNames.add(recordTypeInfo.getDeveloperName());
          }
        }
        if (!recordTypeNames.isEmpty()) {
          objectRecordTypesMap.put(salesforceObj, recordTypeNames);
        }
      }
    }
    catch(CalloutException e){
      System.debug('Error in fetching object record types:' + e.getMessage());
    }
    return objectRecordTypesMap;
  }
```

Test:

```
@isTest
    static void testFetchObjectRecordTypes() {
        // Test with valid SObject names
        List<String> sObjectList = new List<String>{'Account', 'Contact'};
        Test.startTest();
        Map<String, List<String>> result = MappingService.fetchObjectRecordTypes(sObjectList);
        System.assertEquals(2, result.size());
        System.assertNotEquals(null, result.get('Account'));
        System.assertNotEquals(null, result.get('Contact'));

        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

This test case won't work for the obvious reasons mentioned above.

Comment: The best way to resolve this is to query in the testmethod for sobjectTypes that have recordtypes (using SOQL) and then use those sobjectTypes in the construction of the arguments to the method-under-test. This way, if the org has no recordtypes, it works fine and if it does have record types, you verify that the method returns what is known about the org

Comment: Thank you so much. It sounds like a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when I have to write testmethods where

- the data is unmockable
- the test depends on org data

Then, I write the testmethod to

- query the org data
- if none found, simply return
- if found, I use the org data as my inputs for the code-under-test

In your case, because the code-under-test, method `fetchObjectRecordTypes` relies on `SObjectDescribe`, you'll need to ...

- Query for all RecordType `[SELECT Id, DeveloperName, SObjectType FROM RecordType ORDER BY SObjectType, DeveloperName]`
- If none found, return
- If found, choose the first SObjectType and get all of its RecordTypes.  This becomes the expected results
- For the first SObjectType, call your method `fetchObjectRecordTypes`. If you want to test list processing, make a list of the same SObjectType twice.